# Split the current month in to weeks in php

Tags: php, date, date-range

I want to split the current month in to weeks like first day to saturday and then sunday to next saturday.For ex: for May month, So i want to split that like

```
2016-05-01 to 2016-05-07
2016-05-08 to 2016-05-14
2016-05-15 to 2016-05-21
2016-05-22 to 2016-05-28
2016-05-29 to 2016-05-31
```

if i try the below code,i didnt get exact result.

```
<?php

$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-06-01'));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-06-30'));
$i=1;
for($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date; $date = date('Y-m-d',       strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'))) {
    echo getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date, $i);
    echo "\n";
    $i++;
}

function getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date, $i) {
    $week =  date('W', strtotime($date));
    $year =  date('Y', strtotime($date));

    $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+1")); 
    if($from < $start_date) $from = $start_date;

    $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-7"));   
    if($to > $end_date) $to = $end_date;

    echo $from." - ".$to.'<br>';    
}

?>
```

i got like

```
2016-05-01 - 2016-05-01
2016-05-01 - 2016-05-08
2016-05-08 - 2016-05-15
2016-05-15 - 2016-05-22
2016-05-22 - 2016-05-29
```

In for loop, while checking last set of days, conditon get failed .so it doesnt calculate 30,31.

How can i do that?

Comment: may be this is the problem W - The ISO-8601 week number of year (weeks starting on Monday)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime, DatePeriod and DateInterval are your friends to do that quickly!

[See online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f36a0af5401bfaa1847c8711f4fdbec67fed042).

```php
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Awnser to http://stackoverflow.com/q/37224961/392725
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37228497/392725
 */
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

function getWeekDates(DateTimeInterface $date, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dt        = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($date);
  $first_day = $dt->modify('first day of this month');
  $last_day  = $dt->modify('last day of this month');
  $period    = new \DatePeriod(
    $first_day,
    \DateInterval::createFromDateString('sunday this week'),
    $last_day,
    \DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE
  );

  $weeks = [$first_day->format($format)];
  foreach ($period as $d) {
    $weeks[] = $d->modify('-1 day')->format($format);
    $weeks[] = $d->format($format);
  }
  $weeks[] = $last_day->format($format);

  return array_chunk($weeks, 2);
}

echo "Weeks of the current month:\n";
$weeks = getWeekDates(new \DateTime('now'));
array_walk($weeks, function ($week) {
  vprintf("%s to %s\n", $week);
});

echo "\nWeeks of the month may 2016:\n";
$weeks = getWeekDates(new \DateTime('2016-05'));
array_walk($weeks, function ($week) {
  vprintf("%s to %s\n", $week);
});

echo "\nWeeks of the month june 2016:\n";
$weeks = getWeekDates(new \DateTime('2016-06'));
array_walk($weeks, function ($week) {
  vprintf("%s to %s\n", $week);
});

echo "\nWeeks of the month october 2016:\n";
$weeks = getWeekDates(new \DateTime('2016-10'));
array_walk($weeks, function ($week) {
  vprintf("%s to %s\n", $week);
});
```

**Result:**

```
Weeks of the current month:
2016-05-01 to 2016-05-07
2016-05-08 to 2016-05-14
2016-05-15 to 2016-05-21
2016-05-22 to 2016-05-28
2016-05-29 to 2016-05-31

Weeks of the month may 2016:
2016-05-01 to 2016-05-07
2016-05-08 to 2016-05-14
2016-05-15 to 2016-05-21
2016-05-22 to 2016-05-28
2016-05-29 to 2016-05-31

Weeks of the month june 2016:
2016-06-01 to 2016-06-04
2016-06-05 to 2016-06-11
2016-06-12 to 2016-06-18
2016-06-19 to 2016-06-25
2016-06-26 to 2016-06-30

Weeks of the month october 2016:
2016-10-01 to 2016-10-01
2016-10-02 to 2016-10-08
2016-10-09 to 2016-10-15
2016-10-16 to 2016-10-22
2016-10-23 to 2016-10-29
2016-10-30 to 2016-10-31
```

Comment: this seems to error on php7 - causes max timeout :S

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, I assume you can change month variable according to your need.

```
$month=5;//pass here your month
$first_date = date("Y-m-1");
do{
  $last_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($first_date. " +6 days"));
  $month = date("m",strtotime($last_date));
  if($month!=5)
    $last_date = date("Y-m-t");

  echo "<br>".$first_date." - ".$last_date;
  $first_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($last_date. " +1 days"));
}while($month == 5);
```

Check here : https://eval.in/571521

Answer (score 1):

Modified Rishi's code, fixed some problem places and solved the problem of leap years when splitting February into weeks:

```
$weeks = monthToWeeks(2016, '02');

print_r($weeks); 

function monthToWeeks($y, $m)
{
    $weeks = [];
    $month = $m;
    $first_date = date("{$y}-{$m}-01");

    do {
        $last_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($first_date. " +6 days"));
        $month = date("m", strtotime($last_date));

        if ($month != $m) {
            $last_date = date("Y-m-t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1, $y)); 

            if ($first_date > $last_date) {
                break;
            }
         }  

         $weeks[] = [$first_date, $last_date];

         $first_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($last_date. " +1 days"));

    } while($month == intval($m));

    return $weeks;    
}
```

You may try it here https://eval.in/643724

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSaturdays($y, $m)
{
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime("first saturday of $y-$m"),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('next saturday'),
        new DateTime("last day of $y-$m")
    );
}


function list_week_days($year, $month) {
    $first_month_day =  new DateTime("first day of $year-$month") ;
    echo $first_month_day->format("Y-m-d\n") . '-';
    foreach (getSaturdays($year, $month) as $saturday) {
        echo $saturday->format(" Y-m-d\n");
        echo '-<br>';
        $sunday  = $saturday->modify('next Sunday');
        echo $sunday->format(" Y-m-d\n");

    }
    $last_month_day =  new DateTime("last day of $year-$month");
    echo $last_month_day->format("Y-m-d\n");
}


list_week_days(2016, 5);
```

p.s.
I  encorege you to use DateTime class